# Windows Store Ubuntu Install

Tags: system-installation, windows

I'm pretty new to Linux, and messed around with it for a while and when I wanted to get serious... I uninstalled it,and reinstalled it. It's not life changing but I want to get rid of the -old at the end of the machines name.

I google and bing'd it and ended up following some tutorials for changing and removing user names. Did not help. I think this will be a good learning opportunity and want to understand how the machine functions.

So I want it to go from UserName@Machine-old:~$ to... UserName@machine:$

let me know, if you can also explain a little of whats happening that would be helpful.

Comment: So if I understand, you want to change your Ubuntu system hostname from "machine-old" to "machine" ? You can edit the /etc/hostname file and the /etc/hosts file. Then reboot.

Comment: Assuming that you're using a graphical install, you can go to settings and scroll down to "About" and change it there as well.